# Not loading css file in executable jar javafx8

Tags: java, javafx

I am getting an error while I try to run executable jar file.

```
lis 09, 2014 8:20:34 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged WARNING: Resource "/styles.css" not found.
```

When I'm running application from IDE, everything is OK. I try a several solution, but neither worked.

**1.**

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles.css").toExternalForm());
```

**2.**

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("styles.css");
```

**3.**

```
scene.getStylesheets().addAll(new File("/styles.css").toURI().toString());
```

**4**

```
    InputStream inputStream = MainApp.class.getResourceAsStream("/styles.css");
    File tempStyleSheetDest = File.createTempFile("javafx_stylesheet", "");
    tempStyleSheetDest.deleteOnExit();
    Files.copy(inputStream, tempStyleSheetDest.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(tempStyleSheetDest.toURI().toString());
```

And another similar. I struggle this a few hours and I have no more ideas. 
I'm using **maven, java1.8_u20**.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());
```

without the '/' in the beginning...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven, make sure to setup your resources folder correctly. Create a resource folder and copy your **style.css** file inside then add something like this to your pom.xml:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

You have to make sure that the **style.css** file ends up inside the jar in the location you are requesting with the getClass().getResource() method (that's usually a relative path inside the class package folders or an absolute one if you add the "/" at the front). In Jens-Peter Haack defense, read this (from the getResource() javadoc) :

> "If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
>   the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.  Otherwise,
>   the absolute name is of the following form: 
>   modified_package_name/name  Where the modified_package_name is the
>   package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e')."
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-

So if you stick with the '/' at the front of the filename make sure your **style.css** file ends up in the root of your jar file, if not make sure it ends up in a path relative to the class location inside your jar.

Answer (score 0):

My sample executable jar with CSS:

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MPCU.png)

through this file management, I did and resolve your problem.

`src
|-drawable
|    |-bg.png
|
|-javaClass
|    |-mainApp.java
|    |-myStyle.css
|`

set external CSS file:
`scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("myStyle.css").toExternalForm());`

get external Image in other directory:
`-fx-background-image: url('../drawable/bg.png');`

Comment: I respect your answer and reaction, but can you tell to me why and how did I resolve @mike192's problem?

Comment: me having been wrong and sloppy <g> Missed the context is css/fxml ..